# @selector and other class (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, object, action, selector

Inside an object I use NSMenu's `addItemWithTitle:action:keyEquivalent:` to create NSMenuItems. The problem is that I wish to call a method on another object as action. The `action:` part takes an `@selector` as parameter and I don't know how to use this to call methods on other objects. I could create a method inside the object creating the NSMenu and then from that object I could call the method I would like to call on another object.. But then I don't know any good naming convention for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`setTarget:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenuItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMenuItem/setTarget:) on the newly created `NSMenuItem` object to set the target object for the action message. Here's an example from [The Objectvive-C Programming Language: Selectors](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Articles/ocSelectors.html), which does similar thing for a table cell:

```
[myButtonCell setAction:@selector(reapTheWind:)];  
[myButtonCell setTarget:anObject];
```

Comment: Thanks a million! Why didn't I think of that.

Comment: what is the target when it is not explicitly set?

Comment: If the target is `nil` the application will go up the responder chain to find an object that responds to the action.