# designing a view with interface builder

Tags: iphone, ios, view, interface-builder

I'm new to interface builder.

I'd like to design a view in interface builder.
I know I can load the view via 'loadNibNamed'.

Now, suppose there will be two buttons(or two tap gesture recognizers) in the view, and when those buttons are touched, some functions need to fire.
How do I connect(?) the touch to some functions of the viewController that I called the 'loadNibNamed' from?

The view will be a pop-up view ([PopUp view](https://github.com/sonsongithub/PopupView)) with two buttons(or tap gesture recognizers).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up outlets from your interface builder objects (buttons) to your class.

To do this, you need to make your class that calls "loadNibNamed" as a delegate class. Then synthesize the button so it is a property.

Once you do that add the selector:

```
 [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed)
```

forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

The better way would be to write a new class for that particular view. Then if you want to catch the event in the class that called "loadNibNamed" you can set the target to something else:

```
[button addTarget:(UIMyClass)sender action:@selector(buttonPressed)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

There should be lots of tutorials out there :) - btw have you considered upgrading your xcode and using storyboards?

--EDIT:--

The problem happens because you are mixing coding with interface building. I think you still need to make a viewcontroller class for your new view, but you can change the target of the selector to the calling class.

See more here about selectors: [@selector and other class (Objective-C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206623/selector-and-other-class-objective-c)

There is a similar question here about pushing data to a new view programatically:

[Can we pass a parameter to view did load or view will appear of other class from a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435193/can-we-pass-a-parameter-to-view-did-load-or-view-will-appear-of-other-class-from)

Comment: Thanks for input. where do I synthesize the button? Since I'm not making a viewController that goes with this view.. I don't see where I could declare the buttons.. I guess there must be lots of tutorials, I looked over, but still confused. and where does the code (addTarget:action:) reside?

Comment: Thank you very much, but I'm not getting it. :(

Comment: How about this? create the view in code. set up the define the selector in the view class and call addTarget:action: from awakeFromNib. Let the view have a delegate and call delegate's method from the action selector.

Comment: Not sure if that will work, it depends where the selector is and what the target for it is. But try it I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to IB there are three steps.

1. Add the method name in your .h (header) file, i.e.

   -(IBAction)someMethod:(id) sender;
2. Save the modified .h file.
3. Open Interface Builder.
4. Open the File Owner window under the Tools menu I believe.
5. Cntrl+Click on the File Owner selection under the File Owner Window.
   A black window should appear with a bunch of interface options under it.  A small black circle should appear next to someMethod
6. Drag that small black circle (a blue line should appear) onto the button you want your method to connect to.  Another menu should appear.  Choose an appropriate action (something like on touch or something like that).  Repeat for the second button.
7. In the IB for each button give them a tag in the attributes list under the Properties (I believe). If you need the Properties window look under the Tools menu again.  Go to the Tag section and give each button a different tag. (1, 2, 3 ... etc).
8. Implement the method in the .m file.  Make sure you differentiate your actions for which button the user selects, i.e. if (sender.tag == 1) {...} else if (sender.tag == 2) {...}

Save and run.

The end.